# NServiceBus analytics

Tags: nservicebus, serviceinsight

We have gone with our first integration deployment into production with NServiceBus. ServiceInsight and ServicePulse are very handy, especially ServiceInsight - it is very helpful to understand things during go-live activities, even though it is sluggish.

I would like to see if there are any easy ways to pull information from ServiceControl into Excel to come up with basic analytics such as volume of messages/events we process, messages/event that takes more time, failed messages, busy endpoints, peak period  etc.

Has anyone done this or is there something available already or any recommended ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here: http://code972.com/blog/2015/02/83-real-time-analytics-for-nservicebus-powered-systems-using-elasticsearch

I used Elasticsearch + Kibana to provide real-time analytics for the NServiceBus platform.

You can also export the data directly from ServiceControl's RavenDB instance into CSV and then Excel - but that's indeed a lot less pretty.